# Authenticate users with firebase using compose

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-authentication, android-jetpack-compose

I am currently trying to learn how to make autentication possible for users in jetpack compose. The user should first register an e-mail and a password in a registration screen(as seen below). Then the information should be saved in the firebase authentication section. The user will be directed back to the sign-in page and can then sign in using their registered e-mail and password. I am sort of familiar doing this with old xml and binding but not in compose.

I have already set up an firebase project and linked it to this project!

How can I achieve this using compose ?

This is my Registration screen:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun RegistrationForUsers(
    onSignUpClick: () -> Unit,
    ) {

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(30.dp)
    ) {

        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.Start
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "Sign Up",
                color = LightBlue,
                style = TextStyle(
                    fontSize = 40.sp,
                    fontFamily = FontFamily.SansSerif,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                )
            )

            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .wrapContentSize()
                    .padding(top = 5.dp)
            )

            {
                val firstName = remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue()) }
                val lastName = remember { mutableStateOf("") }


                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top,
                    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.Start,
                ) {
                    // FirstName of the User
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(40.dp))
                    
                    // Email of the User
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 15.dp))
                    OutlinedTextField(
                        value = lastName.value,
                        onValueChange = { newText ->
                            lastName.value = newText
                        },

                        label = { Text(text = "E-mail") },
                        singleLine = true,
                        leadingIcon = {
                            Icon(
                                imageVector = Icons.Default.Email,
                                contentDescription = null
                            )
                        },
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth(190F),

                        )


                    // Password of the User
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 15.dp))
                    OutlinedTextField(
                        value = lastName.value,
                        onValueChange = { newText ->
                            lastName.value = newText
                        },

                        label = { Text(text = "Password") },
                        singleLine = true,
                        leadingIcon = {
                            Icon(
                                imageVector = Icons.Default.Lock,
                                contentDescription = null
                            )
                        },
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth(190F),

                        )

                    // Confirm Password of the User
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 15.dp))
                    OutlinedTextField(
                        value = lastName.value,
                        onValueChange = { newText ->
                            lastName.value = newText
                        },

                        label = { Text(text = "Confirm Password") },
                        singleLine = true,
                        leadingIcon = {
                            Icon(
                                imageVector = Icons.Default.Lock,
                                contentDescription = null
                            )
                        },
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth(190F),

                        )

                    // Register BUTTON
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(60.dp))
                    Box(modifier = Modifier.padding(40.dp, 0.dp, 40.dp, 0.dp)) {
                        Button(
                            onClick = {  }, // Sends the user to Sign In screen
                            shape = RoundedCornerShape(50.dp),
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .fillMaxWidth()
                                .height(50.dp)
                        ) {
                            Text(text = "Sign Up", fontSize = 17.sp, fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold)
                        }
                    }

                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
                    ClickableText(
                        text = AnnotatedString("Already have an account?"),
                        onClick = { onSignUpClick.invoke() },
                        modifier = Modifier.wrapContentSize(),
                        style = TextStyle(
                            fontSize = 13.sp,
                            fontFamily = FontFamily.Default,
                        ),
                    )


                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors? Besides that, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-handle-firebase-authentication-in-clean-architecture-using-jetpack-compose-e9929c0e31f8) and this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-google-one-tap-in-jetpack-compose-60b30e621d0d) will help you understand the flow. Both are using Jetpack Compose. And both have online repos.

Comment: I added this code because I am un-sure of how to connect this to firebase. When I click register button, how can I make it so that the information is saved into firebase authentication? Do I create 2 data classes and then connect them to firebase auth and then firebase to compose or ?

Comment: Will check the resources out and see if they solve the problem and will update here after. Aprreciate the help!

Comment: Have you tried to read the code in the first resource? And yes, when you click register, you have to get user input and perform the authentication. When the authentication is complete, write that data to Firestore, or Realtime Database.

Comment: Yes, currently reading the first source. It seems to match with what I am trying to achieve! ok, I see. Just curious as well, is there a way to simultaneously register user info such as firstname, lastname,  e-mail and password into firebase realtime database and at the same time register only e-mail in firebase authentication when user clicks registration ?

Comment: No, you cannot do that simultaneously. You have to do one operation after the other.

Comment: ah ok I understand, Well, will try to focus on firebase auth then and learn after your source how to implement it using a clean mvvm architecture and will see if I can solve it.  Hopefully it will work!

Comment: Good luck with that. If you have a hard time implementing it, please post a new question, here on StackOverflow, so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: Alright will do that! Appreciate the help and feedback as well! :)